# libgpiod API usage (Linux shared libraries)

Tags: c, api, embedded-linux, gpio, dynamic-library

Does anyone have any experience with the libgpiod API?  I have installed it on my linux platform but am unable to call its library functions.

I installed by:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git
cd libgpiod
./autogen.sh
make
make install
```

Afterwards, I see the **libgpiod.so** library in */usr/local/lib/* and **gpiod.h** in */usr/local/include/* (for good measure I ran `ldconfig` as well).  However, when I try to compile the following:

**test.c**

```
#include <gpiod.h>

struct gpio_chip *chip;    

int main(void)
{
    chip = gpio_chip_open("/dev/gpiochip4");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error: `undefined reference to 'gpiod_chip_open'`

Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you compile? Command?

Comment: Using `gcc test.c`

Comment: Not linking? Try: `gcc -lgpiod test.c`

Comment: Thank you!  That compiled.  But when I run, I am told `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` ...

Comment: `libgpiod` is a part of all main Linux distributions. Why do you want to compile it yourself? (Yes I have an experience with it, but I never compiled `libgpiod` myself)

Comment: @Bastinoboy: Check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if the `.so` file path is listed in it. Generally, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` contain the SO files and/or their symlinks. You need to cofirm that to run th executable. Look at this relevant thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime

Comment: @0andriy I am using a custom debian based distro for an embedded device.  It was built a few years ago (not by me) and it doesn't have `libgpiod` .... @Azeem Thanks again! `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` did the trick :)

Comment: Perhaps time to upgrade...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the library for linking with `-l` flag.

Compile it like this:

```
gcc -lgpiod test.c
```

In addition, you might need to configure the runtime paths also for the SO file if it's a custom one. See this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime) for more details on runtime shared object locations.

Comment: This along with another link shared helped me so much with getting rid of a symbol lookup error which I was stuck with

Answer (score 3):

Please try this command:

Install library first:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgpiod-dev
```

Compile command:

```
gcc GPIO_LED.c -o led_read_status -lgpiod
```

Run as root user.

In addition you can use gpio tool for debugging GPIO:

1. gpiodetect
2. gpioinfo
3. gpioset
4. gpioget